# ¿Como puedo usar indexDB en react?

Tags: reactjs

Muy buenas comunidad, el problema que tengo es el siguiente:
Quiero poder mostrar los datos que estan almacenados en indexdb, la parte de crear la base de datos y la funcionalidad de añadir un nuevo registro ya la pude hacer.

El problema que estoy teniendo es poder consumir los datos que estan almacenados para poder iterar sobre ellos y mostrarlos en pantalla. Para esto, dichos datos deben venir en un array lo cual no ocurre con los metodos que te da indexDB. adjunto mi código. Si alguien sabe me ayudaría muchismo.

Muchas gracias!

```
export function createDataBase(changeValueDB) {
   const createDB = window.indexedDB.open('correos', 1)

   createDB.onsuccess = () => {
      changeValueDB(createDB.result)
      readData(createDB.result)
   }

   createDB.onupgradeneeded = (e) => {
      const db = e.target.result
      const objectStore = db.createObjectStore('correos', {
         keyPath: 'id',
         autoIncrement: true,
      })

      objectStore.createIndex('name', 'name', { unique: false })
      objectStore.createIndex('email', 'email', { unique: false })
      objectStore.createIndex('phone', 'phone', { unique: false })

      console.log('Database Creada y Lista: solo 1 vez')
   }
}

export function addData(valueDB, objForAdd) {
   const transaction = valueDB.transaction(['correos'], 'readwrite')
   const objectStore = transaction.objectStore('correos')
   objectStore.add(objForAdd)

   transaction.oncomplete = () => {
      console.log('Cita agregada')
   }
}

export function readData(valueDB) {
   const objectStore = valueDB
      .transaction('correos')
      .objectStore('correos')

   objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = (e) => {
      const cursor = e.target.result
      if (cursor) {
         console.log(cursor)
         cursor.continue()
      } else {
         console.log('NO MORE DATA')
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrías crear un array de objetos dentro de la función readData() en lo que iteras sobre el cursor, y hacer que la función haga return de esos datos.

Los métodos y propiedades de IDBCursor se explican aquí:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor

Según este ejemplo (en la misma página), parece que necesitas saber los campos/keys de antemano:

```
function displayData() {
  var transaction = db.transaction(['rushAlbumList'], "readonly");
  var objectStore = transaction.objectStore('rushAlbumList');

  objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if(cursor) {
      var listItem = document.createElement('li');
      listItem.innerHTML = cursor.value.albumTitle + ', ' + cursor.value.year;
      list.appendChild(listItem);

      cursor.continue();
    } else {
      console.log('Entries all displayed.');
    }
  };
}
```

Algo así:

```
export function readData(valueDB) {

   let a = [];

   const objectStore = valueDB
      .transaction('correos')
      .objectStore('correos')

   objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = (e) => {
      const cursor = e.target.result
      if (cursor) {
         let js = { name: cursor.value.name, email: cursor.value.email }
         a.push(js);
         console.log(cursor)
         cursor.continue()
      } else {
         console.log('NO MORE DATA')
         return a;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Genial tío, el tema es que cuando quiero retornar ese valor en un componente, me sale que el array está vacío. Estoy intentando con un customHook, pero ni idea de momento, alguna idea?